# How to run mutiple include tasks asynchronously in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I use 'include' and 'with_items' to looping over a block of tasks:

```html
---
- name: main file
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1:
      - { name: 'testuser1', groups: 'wheel', time: 10 }
      - { name: 'testuser2', groups: 'root', time: 3 }
  tasks:     
    - name: multiple tasks
      include: multiple.yml item={{item}}
      with_items: "{{ list1 }}"
```

and the multiple.yml is:

```html
---
- name: time before
  shell: date +"%H:%M:%S"

- name: run 
  shell: sleep {{ item.time }}

- name: time after
  shell: date +"%H:%M:%S"
```

The task works well. However, the multiple.yml for each loop are executed serialisely:

```html
TASK [time before] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:00.013440", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.595098", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.581658", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:04", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:04"]}

TASK [run] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 10", "delta": "0:00:10.013043", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:14.859720", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.846677", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

TASK [time after] *******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:00.012656", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.153993", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.141337", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:15", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:15"]}

TASK [time before] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:01.014217", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:16.448480", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.434263", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:15", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:15"]}

TASK [run] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 3", "delta": "0:00:03.012509", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:19.711891", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:16.699382", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

TASK [time after] *******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:01.013766", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:20.973979", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:19.960213", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:19", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:19"]}
```

I want to execute the multiple.yml of each loop asynchronously, so I tried to use async and poll in main file:

```html
---
- name: main file
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1:
      - { name: 'testuser1', groups: 'wheel', time: 10 }
      - { name: 'testuser2', groups: 'root', time: 3 }
  tasks:     
    - name: multiple tasks
      include: multiple.yml item={{item}}
      async: 20  
      poll: 0
      with_items: "{{ list1 }}"
```

The expected result is:

```html
TASK [time before] ******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:00.013440", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.595098", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.581658", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:04", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:04"]}

    TASK [run] ******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 10", "delta": "0:00:10.013043", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:14.859720", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:04.846677", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

    TASK [time after] *******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:00.012656", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.153993", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.141337", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:15", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:15"]}

    TASK [time before] ******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:01.014217", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:16.448480", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:15.434263", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:15", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:04"]}

    TASK [run] ******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sleep 3", "delta": "0:00:03.012509", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:19.711891", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:16.699382", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

    TASK [time after] *******************************************************************************************
    changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date +\"%H:%M:%S\"", "delta": "0:00:01.013766", "end": "2018-11-25 15:56:20.973979", "rc": 0, "start": "2018-11-25 15:56:19.960213", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "15:56:19", "stdout_lines": ["15:56:08"]}
```

But the result of running new main.yml is the same as before, and the multiple.yml of the two loops is not executed asynchronously. I don't kown what the problem is. Is there any advice?

Answer (score 4):

That is a [known issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22716) and is marked as an "improvement," rather than a bug. Feel free to drop a comment or +1 or whatever into the issue, but I would not expect it to be resolved in the near future since that issue has been open since 2017.

---

Separately, it may interest you to know that the "inline variable" syntax has been deprecated in favor of using `vars:`, but even in that case you don't need to because `with_items:` automatically exposes `item` and thus it is implicitly in `vars:` for you. The deprecation is in the ["Note" in the manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing-task-files)

Comment: Thanks for your attention and advise. But I wonder that is there any way to achieve this scenario? Since I have to execute many included xxx.yml asynchronously in Ansible.