# Running multiple Ansible steps in parallel

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have a long playbook that is composed of several largely independent steps (I use it to deploy my test code):

```
    # steps for service 1
    - file:
        # setup config dir for service1
    - template:
        # setup config file for service1
    - community.docker.docker_image:
        # get the image1
    - community.docker.docker_container:
        # have the image1 started

    # steps for service 2
    - file:
        # setup config dir for service2
    - template:
        # setup config file 1 for service2
    - template:
        # setup config file 2 for service2
    - community.docker.docker_image:
        # get the image2
    - community.docker.docker_container:
        # have the image2 started

    # steps for service 3
    - file:
        # setup config dir for service3
    - template:
        # setup config file 1 for service3
    - template:
        # setup config file 2 for service3
    - community.docker.docker_image:
        # get the image3
    - community.docker.docker_container:
        # have the image3 started
```

Obviously when I run it, it runs each of the steps sequentially, taking a bit of time.
Is it possible to somehow make Ansible run each "fat block" (for service1, service2, service3) in parallel in an easy fashion? Basically something to "group" them into a "function" that could then be started and waited for.

In other words, how to make Ansible-equivalent of:

```
block1 & # does service1 stuff
block2 & # does service2 stuff
block3 & # does service3 stuff
wait; wait; wait
```

(I'm a total newbie to Ansible so it's possible I'm missing some reogranisation knowledge).

Comment: There is the possibility for a kind of "fire and forget" for tasks, [Asynchronous actions and poll: 0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0).

Comment: But according [Ansible Issue #28997](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28997) "Allow use of async on blocks" it will not work for [Blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).

Comment: And according [How to run multiple include tasks asynchronously in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465825/) or [Ansible: Can we run an include playbook asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197845/) it seems not to work with `include_` either.

Comment: Hey @U880D - thanks a lot! I think these comments form a valid (unfortunately negative) answer (especially considering your link in the second comment - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/28997#issuecomment-1317224950).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed within the comments there is only the possibility to [run concurrently: `poll = 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0) for tasks.

> *If you want to run multiple tasks in a playbook concurrently, use `async` with `poll` set to 0. When you set `poll: 0`, Ansible starts the task and immediately moves on to the next task without waiting for a result.*

Together with that and in order to decrease the overall runtime of your playbook, you could organize it task centric instead of service centric.

```yaml
vars:

  service_list:
    - service1
    - service2
    - service3

tasks:

# Prepare

- name: Setup config dir for services
  file:
    path: /dir/{{ item }}/
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ service_list }}"

- name: Copy config files for services
  template:
    src: templates/{{ item }}.j2
    dest: /dir/{{ item }}
  loop: "{{ service_list }}"

# Long running tasks, could probably be an include_

- name: "Download the image {{ service_list[0] }}"
  community.docker.docker_image:
    name: "{{ service_list[0] }}"
    source: pull
    pull: true
  async: 600
  poll: 0

- name: "Download the image {{ service_list[1] }}"
  community.docker.docker_image:
    name: "{{ service_list[1] }}"
    source: pull
    pull: true
  async: 600
  poll: 0

- name: "Download the image {{ service_list[2] }}"
  community.docker.docker_image:
    name: "{{ service_list[2] }}"
    source: pull
    pull: true
  async: 600
  poll: 0

# Wait or check

- name: # Needs to be defined
  ...

# Start

- community.docker.docker_container:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    image: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ service_list }}"
```